# z-index fadIn with jQuery cross opacity

Tags: jquery, z-index

I experience a strange thing while using z-index with fadIn on layers with jquery. Without fadeIn but just show there are no problems:

Here's my setup:

```
Layer 1 (-2), position: absolute
Layer 2 (fadeIn) (-1), position: relative
Layer 3 ( none / 1), position: absolute
Layer 4 (fadeIn) (2), position: absolute
```

Since I'm not using a z-index value on Layer 3 the fadIn works fine expect that Layer 3 gets an opacity where it crosses with Layer 1.

If I'm using a z-index value on Layer 3 there is no more opacity crossing with Layer 1 while the transition but Layer 4 will show up only after the fadeIn of Layer 1.

Is there anything I overlooked on the use on z-index or in context with fadeIn? Something that does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution I came to:

**What was wrong:**

All four Layers were children of the div I actually fade in. I suggest while doing that the different z-index status are beeing ignored and "reactivated" once the transition is complete.

**Solution:**

While I didn't change any of the html markup I just added some markup to my script and hided/fadedIn each child seperately at the same time. This somehow keeps all z-index intact.